# Nested nohup mishandle output

Tags: bash, io-redirection, nohup

I have a bash script A (i.e. scripta.sh) which executes another bash script B (i.e. scriptb.sh), running other commands.

A:

```bsh
# Cool logic
scriptb.sh &
```

B:

```bsh
# Cool logic
nohup python3 app.py >> app.log &
```

When I run `nohup scripta.sh >> a.log &`, I get both the outputs of A and app.py into a.log, while app.log is empty.

Why is this happening? How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: cannot reproduce; *scripta*: `sh scriptb &`; *scriptb*: `nohup echo b >> b.log &`; running `nohup sh scripta >> a.log &`, output is as expected in `b.log`, while `a.log` is empty.

Comment: @pLumo the OP is probably using "output" as a generic term for the stuff written to both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @mosvy yes, because apparently I cannot see any difference at the moment. Both errors and output go in that file. I might have to investigate in the behaviour of python output in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't your nohup say "redirecting stderr to stdout"?

That's exactly what happened. `nohup scripta.sh >> a.log &` redirected the stderr to `a.log` (because stderr was a tty when you ran the command from an interactive shell), and then the second `nohup python3 ..` from `scriptb.sh` didn't have to do that any more (because its stderr was not a tty, but `a.log`), and the stderr of `python3 ...` went to `a.log`.

This is what the manpage of `nohup(1)` says:

> If standard  input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file.
>
> If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if  possible,  `$HOME/nohup.out`  otherwise.
>
> **If standard error is a terminal**, redirect it to standard output.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I missed a lot of understanding of the problem. So how would you recommend to run the python script in order to save stdout and stderr in a dedicated log file?

Comment: redirect its stderr explicitly, run it with `nohup python app.py >> app.log 2>&1 &`